# Hiding/displaying Divs onChange

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variety of divs with form fields.  Based on a drop-down list, i need it to display the div corresponding to that value, and hide all the other divs. (Perhaps there's a more efficient way to even do that, rather than load all the divs and just hide them, i'm not sure).

What I have right now is this:

```html
<select id="group" name="group">
   <option></option>
   <option value="8">Testing This Stuff</option>
   <option value="9">Testing Other Stuff</option>
</select>

<div id="8" style="display:none;">**form fields**</div>
<div id="9" style="display:none;">**different form fields**</div>
```

And the current, semi-working javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  var eSelect = document.getElementById('group');
  eSelect.onchange = function() {
     var id = eSelect.selectedIndex;
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
</script>
```

What i'm getting is 'id' is null, so i haven't been able to work past that part yet.

Part 2 would be hiding the old div and displaying the new div (if they were to change the option selected).  Any suggestions?

**Solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var current;
        var eSelect = document.getElementById('group');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            var id = eSelect.value;
            if (current && current != id) {
                document.getElementById(current).style.display = 'none'
            }
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            current = id; 
        }
    }
</script>

<select id="materialsgroup" class="formInput" name="materialsgroup">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="groupid_8">Testing This Stuff</option>
   <option value="groupid_9">Testing Other Stuff</option>
</select>

<div id="groupid_8">**form fields**</div>
<div id="groupid_9">**more form fields**</div>
```

To make the select and divs, this is what I've done:

```php
foreach($groups as $key=>$value)
{
        $valueItem = "groupid_".$value['group_id'];
        $text = $value['title'];
        $htmlString .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $valueItem, $text);
}

echo '<tr>
  <td class="formLabelCell">Group</td>
  <td class="formInputCell">
  <select id="group" class="formInput" name="group">'.$htmlString.'</select></td></tr>';

foreach($groups as $gkey=>$gvalue)
{
   echo '<div id=groupid_'.$groups[$gkey]['group_id'].' style="display:none;">';
   //**Draw the form stuff here**
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing because i can't show the entire thing, but there is an SQL query ran to get all the groups and stores that in the array $groups.  From there, it does a foreach (2 of them because of the placement of elements) to generate the html and echo it to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
var id = eSelect.value;
```

For the second part, if you are using pure javascript (I mean, you're not using a javascript framework like jQuery) maybe a good solution is to load an array containing the div's ids and iterate it, hiding the div != eSelect.value

```
var arrDivs = new Array("1","2","3");
for (var i=0; i < arrDivs.length; i++) {
    if (arrDivs[i] == eSelect.value)
        document.getElementById(arrDivs[i]).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(arrDivs[i]).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: *sigh* i feel dumb.  That worked :P  Any suggestions for the second part though? Hiding a current div and displaying the newly selected option/div?

Comment: I would also suggest not using `8` and `9` as ids. Ids should start with an alpha character. Adding ids dynamically usually works with ints, but if you assume there will be and id of `8` things get funky. Like trying to style `#8`

Comment: This is a very small sliver of the code going into creating these options and divs.  It's a mess of php and sql creating all this.  I just only showed the things necessary.

Comment: Well the main issue there is i never know how many divs need to be created.  It could be different for every user that views it.  But that's why i'm having such difficulty with finding a way to hide the old divs.  Unless there is a way to store the old value somewhere in a global variable and tell it to hide that one, display the new one, update the global variable to the current one.

Comment: @IceBlueFire how did you go did you sort it out? if not i can whip one up

Comment: Yes, you can save the div's id in a global variable. Simply declare it before the line "window.onload = function() {"

Comment: Are you able to generate dinamically the options and the divs? If you can, maybe you can generate the Array with something like this "new Array(<?= $arrayItems ?>);"

Comment: For note, what i'm doing to make the options and divs, i'll post in the top.

Comment: Updated with solution and methods used.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a javascript novice myself, but what about using a current variable to show which div is shown (and therefore knowing which div to hide)?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var current, eSelect = document.getElementById('group');
    eSelect.onchange = function() {
    var id = eSelect.value;
    if (current && current != id) {
        document.getElementById(current).style.display = 'none'
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    current = id; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah. Worked like a charm, thank you very much.  If only i could select multiple answers as 'answers'.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var current, eSelect = document.getElementById('group');
    eSelect.onchange = function() {
    var id = eSelect.value;
    if (current && current != id) {
        document.getElementById(current).style.display = 'none'
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    current = id; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but next time don't just post the code, provide some explation ;)